# How could I use pseudo-element :after :before conditionally

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

If I wanted to only insert a pseudo-element after a link only if the link is followed by another element say ul. How could I do this?

Example:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">blah<!-- insert -> here with CSS --></a>
        <ul>
            <li>More stuff</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">blah 2<!--Do nothing here--></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS I wish could happen:

```
ul li a:after if(next:ul) {
   content:"->";
}
```

I'm not trying to use JavaScript/jQuery. And I realize if conditions are not apart of css. 
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: In general that's not possible. In your specific case, you can use `ul li a:not(:last-child)::after`.

Comment: @RobW add that as an answer that worked!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general it is not possible to select elements based on their next sibling.

In your specific case, you can use `ul li a:not(:last-child)::after`, because it happens that your anchors that are not followed by an `<ul>` element are also the last child element.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use:

```
ul + li a:after {  /* ...css code... */  }
```

Basically this means:

Match an `a` element contained in a `li` element that is immediately preceded by an `ul` element.

---

The `+` operator in CSS is called [adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators).

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. Re-read the question. The OP wants to select all `<a>`s that are not followed by an `ul`.

Comment: @RobW I would like to select all a's that are preceded by ul.

Comment: @JasonFoglia Are you sure that you mean "preceded" (= "comes before")? Your code example suggests that you actually meant "followed". I've edited your question based on this observation, please clarify your real intention.

Comment: @Rob W: Or "a's that precede ul".

Comment: @RobW your observation is correct. I meant followed by not preceded by. So all <a>'s that are followed by <ul> should be targeted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter any element in the `hierarchy/list` of elements you can use the below approach.

`ul li a:not(:nth-last-child(N))::after`

Here `N` is any positive integer traversing from the end; `1` means the last element `2` means second last and so on. Instead of `ul li` use any selector here

For more information visit [nth-last-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child).